# RFMesh (NRF24) for STM32F1

Tags: arduino-ide, nrf24l01+, stm32

I wanted to know the RFMesh library available for Arduino Uno can be used for STM32F1? Will it work? Or they have seperate set of library for STM32

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: I have not yet tried. But wanted to work on that. But I am not sure will it work with STM32 or not. But when I compiled the sketch in Arduino IDE by selecting STM32F1 from board manager it compiled without any error. So I wanted to put this in front of community.